# PHP: openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key

Tags: php, encryption, rsa

I have this code to create a RSA 4096 public and private key to encrypt and decrypt a string.

Code:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    "config" => "C:/xampp/php/extras/openssl/openssl.cnf",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);

// Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);

// Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

$data = 'Hello, World!';

// Encrypt the data to $encrypted using the public key
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubKey);

echo $encrypted;

// Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privKey);

echo $decrypted;
?>
```

It creates the keys, encrypts `data` string (`Hello, World!`) but when tries to decrypt `encrypted` string, an error occurs:

**Warning**: openssl_private_decrypt(): key parameter is not a valid private key in **C:\xampp\htdocs\rsa\index.php** on line **26**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this worked for me:

Change `openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);` to `openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey, NULL, $config);`.

Comment: You may want to store the key in a protected (PKCS#12) key container or something similar. Storing the plain bytes is of course pretty dangerous. Similarly, for your scheme to be useful, the public key needs to be *trusted* at the receiver.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to export the key private like that, at least not until you save it somewhere secure:

```
$config = array(
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
);

$pki     = openssl_pkey_new($config);
$public  = openssl_pkey_get_public(
    openssl_pkey_get_details($pki)['key']
); // why on earth did they implement it like this? so clunky.
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private($pki);

$data = 'Hello, World!';

openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $public);
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $private);

var_dump(
    bin2hex($encrypted),
    $decrypted
);
```

Comment: I guess that storing and retrieving a private key can be considered a rather valid use case. Not storing it is rather dumb, especially for RSA where key pair generation is expensive.